# What's an easy way to setup Oauth for an Amazon Alexa Connected Home skill?

Tags: oauth, amazon-echo

I'm trying to prototype an Alexa Connected Home skill and one of the requirements is linking a user's account using Oauth 2.0. Since I'm just building a prototype and I don't have an Oauth server up and running what's the easiest way for me satisfy Amazon Oauth requirement?

I've tried following the instructions on [Tips for Using Login with Amazon in Alexa Connected Home CoHo Skills](https://developer.amazon.com/public/community/post/TxNL8HYBBE7YTE/Tips-for-Using-Login-with-Amazon-in-Alexa-Connected-Home-CoHo-Skills) but it failed with an uninformative error message no matter what I tried.

- Has anyone gotten Login with Amazon to work with Alexa Connected Home?
- Is there an easy to use Oauth provider that I could use?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

tl;dr

**Login With Amazon Console:**

```
Allowed Origins: https://amazon.com
Allowed Return URLs: <copied from "Redirect URL" in the Alexa Developer Console>
```

**Alexa Developer Console:**

```
Authorization URL: https://www.amazon.com/ap/oa
Access Token URI: https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token
Scope: profile:user_id
Client Id: <copied from "Client Id" in the Login With Amazon Console. eg. amzn1.application-oa2-client.xxxxxxxxxxx >
Client Secret: <copied from "Client Secret" in the Login With Amazon Console.>
```

---

I was able to use Login with Amazon as the Oauth provider. I followed the documentation in the [Login with Amazon Web Developer Guide](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/lwa/dev/docs/website-developer-guide._TTH_.pdf) and found the configuration that I had been missing.

To get Login With Amazon to work I did the following:

- Open the Amazon Alexa developer console and go to the configuration tab of your skill (the page that has the information about Account Linking.
- Set the **Authorization URL** to `https://www.amazon.com/ap/oa`
- Set the **Scope** to `profile:user_id`
- Set the **Access Token URI** to `https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token`
- copy the **Redirect URL** that is in this page for the Login with Amazon configuration (example Redirect URL: https://pitangui.amazon.com/api/skill/link/xxxxxxxxx ).
- Follow Steps 1, 2, and most of 3 from [Tips for Using Login with Amazon in Alexa Connected Home CoHo Skills](https://developer.amazon.com/public/community/post/TxNL8HYBBE7YTE/Tips-for-Using-Login-with-Amazon-in-Alexa-Connected-Home-CoHo-Skills) for "Using Login with Amazon as your OAuth provider".

> **Step 1 - Create a New Security profile**
>
> To create a new security profile on Login with Amazon, go the Developer Console and navigate to Login with Amazon by clicking on Apps & Services. Once you are on the Login with Amazon developer console page, click the Create a New Security Profile button.
>
> [image: https://cdn.amazonblogs.com/developer_blog/images/lwa5.png]
>
> Fill in the required information and hit Save.
>
> [image: https://cdn.amazonblogs.com/developer_blog/images/lwa6.png]
>
> **Step 2 - Obtain Your OAuth Credentials**
>
> Your newly created security profile will now be available in the list of Login with Amazon Configurations.
>
> [image: https://cdn.amazonblogs.com/developer_blog/images/lwa7.png]
>
> You will receive the Client ID and Client Secret.  Please include this information when you submit your skill adapter for test provisioning.
>
> [image: https://cdn.amazonblogs.com/developer_blog/images/lwa8.png]
>
> Click Show.
>
> **Step 3 - Whitelist Your Alexa Connected Home Skill**
>
> Next, we need to whitelist the Alexa Connected Home skill’s endpoints within your Login with Amazon security profile.  First, enter the Web Settings of your security profile:
>
> [image: https://cdn.amazonblogs.com/developer_blog/images/lwa9.png]
>   Next, click Edit on the page, and enter the following data:

- This is when I stopped following the instructions from that blog post. I now set the **Allowed Origins** and **Allowed Return URLs**. The **Allowed Origins** should be `https://amazon.com`, and the **Allowed Return URLs** should be the **Redirect URL** copied from the Account Linking page from the Alexa Developer Console
- Copy both the **Client Id** and the **Client Secret** from the Login With Amazon Console and paste them into the **Client Id** and **Client Secret** fields of the Alexa Developer Console.

Comment: did you have an issue that after successful linking and closing the linking pages, the button "Enable skill" has not changed and there is still a message "Account linking required"? No devices found upon discovery

Comment: Yes I got lots of unhelpful error messages when setting up oauth. But once oauth was setup then the Alexa skill worked.

Comment: I managed to make it work. Actually, I still see this behavior - "Enable skill" button is not updated after successful link with Amazon account, until I click another tab in the app and return back. This might be an app bug. Device discovery was another issue. Everything was correct, I just had to recreate the lambda function to make it work. All this seems to me pretty buggy.

Comment: Excellent, it worked. The docs for this are not intuitive at all IMO, so thank you so much. You should definitely mark your own answer as accepted.

Comment: Hi Alex,
I did the skill configuration as in the same way,
but while doing account linking ,I got the below error,Please help me out 

[Skill Configuration ]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4kuB.png
[Account linking]] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLVUo.png
[Alexa Error] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/84clt.png